# passing variable to simple form symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is my _form_item partial in which I used symbol :order_item

```
<%= simple_form_for :order_item do |f| %>
.....
<% end %>
```

here is my view in which I want to render that partial:

```
<%= content_tag_for :tr , @order.order_items do |i| %>
<div class="hide">
<%= render :partial => "form_item" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

How can I pass "i" object to :order_item?

**UPDATE:**
I prefer to keep it ":order_item" instead of changing it to something like "foo".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `i` as a locals to the partial like follows:

```
<%= render :partial => "form_item", :i => i %>
```

and you'll have `i` available in the `_form_item` partial.

**Update:**

Local variables passed to partials are variables and not symbols.  You could keep the name `order_item` like follows:

```
<%= render :partial => "form_item", :order_item => i %>
```

And update your `order_item` partial as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for order_item do |f| %>
.....
<% end %>
```

I think I understand why you do not want to change `:order_item` to just `order_item`.  I think you are going to have to update your other calls to pass in local variable `order_item` where ever you are making a call to this partial.

Comment: I just want to pass it to that instance , I don't want to change the code and use i variable in it.

Comment: @Pooya, I don't understand, do you mean to say you want to use `i` in `form_for` i.e. `order_item` should hold the value of `i`?

Comment: @vinodadhikary, yeah it should hold the value of i

Comment: @Pooya, I don't think that is possible.  Local variables passed to partials are variables in partial not symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
<%= render partial: 'form_item', locals: {order_item: i} %>
```

or a shorthand:

```
<%= render 'form_item', order_item: i %>
```

And in your `form_item` partial you should have:

```
<%= simple_form_for order_item do |f| %>
...
```

Comment: I'd tried it before but it didn't work.form is rendered with empty fields ( it means that the form is not using i object)

Comment: I had not changed :order_item to order_item. I did it and now I get : `undefined local variable or method 'order_item' for #<#<Class:0xac52574>:0xac46288>`

Comment: @Pooya So what do you have in the view in which you want to render this partial?

Comment: What do you mean by "what do you have in the view"?

Comment: I put it in the question.

Comment: @Pooya, like I wrote in my answer, you should have:

`<%= render 'form_item', order_item: i %`.

Comment: now my code is like what you said. it is `<%= render 'form_item', order_item: i %>` but I'm getting that error.

Comment: @Pooya what about `<%= render partial: 'form_item', locals: {order_item: i} %>`?

Comment: Still getting error :| maybe this is a kind of rails 4 bug. hmm?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
<%= simple_form_for item do |f| %>
.
.
<% end %>
```

and render the partial via

```
<%= render :partial => 'form_item', :locals => { :item => i } %>
```

Comment: I want to use this form for new action too and so I prefer to keep it :order_item instead of item. is there any other way?

Comment: No, not as far as I know. SimpleForm guesses the class from the symbol and instantiates a new object itself, i.e. without setting any attributes. So you need to change :order_item to an instance variable. Following strict MVC instantiating a variable in the view is a bad style anyway. That's the controller's task, the controller's the mediator between model and views. Views should not know anything about underlying the model structure.